# WinForms Thread-safe Controls

Tags: multithreading, winforms, controls

I spend a lot of time working with Windows Forms controls but from a background worker thread - I suppose this is good practice really since you don't want your form to be locking up when people click buttons. To be honest, with just about everything GUI related action I normally do in a background worker thread, so the interface is nice an responsive to the user (Wish more people would do that!).

So my question is... every time I have to interact with controls I have to "Invoke" them, with something like:

```
if (control.InvokeRequired)
{
    //
}
```

Standard practice right? However, this leads me to some terribly messy code, because just about every control type I have, I need a MethodInvoker delegate or something. It's adding thousands of lines of code to my protects, and its terribly time consuming.

I currently have hundreds of "property setting" methods like:

```
private void Safe_SetLableText(Label control, string text)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            control.Text = text;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        control.Text = text;
    }
}
```

So, is there some other technique, or way to do this, or some way to being able to always alter a property of a control, no matter what the control is and no matter what thread im in?

something like: (pseudocode)

```
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

private void thing_to_do()
{
    // We are in a background thread now

    DoSomeDatabaseWorkThatTakesALongTime();

    InvokeAnyControls();

    // Do some stuff...
    controlX.Text = "123"
    controlY.Height = 300;
    controlZ.text = ControlA.text;

    RestoreAnyControls();
}
```

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? The new async features in C# 5 should be able to remove quite a lot of this problem.

Comment: We use .NET 2 as a company wide standard.

Comment: @JonSkeet How would async help? I'm curious, it sounds appealing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If all the long-running operations can be performed asynchronously, the OP's method could actually *all* be running in the UI thread, and just asynchronously performing IO etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your `InvokeRequired` code with a delegate, like so:

```
public static void Invoke2<TControl>(this TControl c, Action<TControl> code) where TControl : Control {

    if( c.InvokeRequired ) c.Invoke( delegate() { code(c); } );
    else code(c);
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
private void Safe_SetLableText(Label control, string text) {
    control.Invoke2( c => c.Text = text );
}
```

Of course you might want better names than `Invoke2`, but I hope the idea sits will with you. Note that the lambda-expression syntax is a C# 3.0 feature, but the `Action<T>` delegate is part of .NET 2.0, so this will compile against the .NET Framework 2.0 so long as you're VS2008 or later.

Comment: It might be worth showing an example with a statement lambda, to set multiple properties in one block, too.

Comment: This is about the same as my existing situation where I have to have a Method for each property I want to set. I'm not sure if you could reliably cast the Label to a generic "Control"? I'm kinda looking for a one-method-fits-all solution.

Comment: @user2542014 This is a one-size-fits-all solution: see that the wrapping extension method is generic and will strongly-type any `Control` subclass, so your method `Safe_SetLableText` is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, after testing you technique, you are right, so im happy to give the solution to you. However I am also going to provide some feed back of my own since one of the things that i wanted to achieve was to simplify my code and as you will see below - it very much is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting an answer to my own question because I think it will add value to the community.

1) I wanted to "simplify" my code, and one if the most important finds was that that the:

```
control.InvokeRequired
```

really isnt needed... its pretty much a given. Importantly, you CAN rely on the fact that the control will need to be invoked if you are in a background (or non-UI) thread.

2) The invocation travels "UP" the control tree, so if you have:

Form > Control > Control inside Control > etc > etc

You only need to invoke "Form" (top most), and then you can alter the properties of the child elements.

So here is my clean and simple solution to working with background workers (or non-UI threads). I have just tested this now and it works great.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.bgDoWork);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.bgComplete);
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bgComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You are not in the UI thread now, so you can Invoke without error
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            // Now you can change any property an any control within this form.
            // Remember "this" refers to Form1.
            this.label1.Text = "test123";
            this.label2.Text = "test456";
            this.label3.Text = this.label4.Text;

            // You can set progress bars too, not just label text
        }
    }

    private void bgDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something that takes a long time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using the Background worker why don't you 'misuse' [OnProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onprogresschanged.aspx)?

```
private void thing_to_do()
{
    // We are in a background thread now
    DoSomeDatabaseWorkThatTakesALongTime();

    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(1, "state");

    DoSomeMoreDatabaseWorkThatTakesALongTime();

    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(2, YourObjectHere);
}

void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs progressArgs)
{
   switch(progressArgs.ProgressPercentage)
   {
       case 1:
          // Do some stuff...
          controlX.Text = "123"
          controlY.Height = 300;
          controlZ.text = ControlA.text;
       break;
       case 2:
          // other stuff
          YourObject obj = (YourObject) progressArgs.UserState;
          // wahtever...
       break;
       default:
       break;
   }

}
```